# how to setup data file when create rest data source using json format

Tags: apex

"data": [         {             "HPI": "469075",             "id": "1241",             "tranline": "1",             "abbrevtype": "销售订单",             "tranid": "SO0000000078",             "otherrefnum": "112-3785580-7573811",             "custbody_dps_old_sales_no": null,             "createddate": "2022-12-09 11:57:18",             "trandate": "2022-12-06 00:00:00"         },         {             "HPI": "491260",             "id": "1242",             "tranline": "1",             "abbrevtype": "销售订单",             "tranid": "SO0000000080",             "otherrefnum": "113-9333754-0007447",             "custbody_dps_old_sales_no": null,             "createddate": "2022-12-09 11:57:23",             "trandate": "2022-11-26 00:00:00"          }                ] } according to oracle help to setup them, I set row selector is 'data' and for column selector using [0]...[n], but the respone parased value havn't correctly show

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.